# Convert absolute to relative url with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

*(I searched, and found lots of questions about converting relative to absolute urls, but nothing for absolute to relative.)*

I'd like to take input from a form field and end up with a relative url. Ideally, this would be able to handle any of the following inputs and end up with `/page-slug`.

- `http://example.com/page-slug`
- `http://www.example.com/page-slug`
- `https://example.com/page-slug`
- `https://www.example.com/page-slug`
- `example.com/page-slug`
- `/page-slug`
- And maybe more I'm not thinking of...?

Edit: I'd also like this to work for something where the relative url is e.g. `/page/post` (i.e. something with more than one slash).

Comment: I'd reverse the string, match everything up to the first slash, and then reverse what you matched

Comment: Remove everything up to the first forward-slash?

Comment: @SimpleCoder - would that work if the relative url was something like /page/post? I'll edit to reflect that scenario.

Comment: @Zirak I'm not sure I follow. There are two forward slashes in "http://". I suppose that could work if I first removed any instances of http:// or https://, though. I'm guessing there might be a more elegant solution, though.

Comment: No, you're right, it won't. Go with steveo225's method.

Comment: I believe the term you're looking for is "Path Canonicalization", and maybe try a combination of [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) & [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)?

Comment: `parse_url()` wont do it for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) if you are always working with URLs. Specifically:

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)
```

FYI, I tested it against all your input, and it worked on all except: `example.com/page-slug`

Answer (score 3):

Try this regexp.

```
#^              The start of the string
(
   ://          Match either ://
   |            Or
   [^/]         Not a /
)*              Any number of times
#
```

And replace it with the empty string.

```
$pattern = '#^(://|[^/])+#';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the part of the URL after the hostname, you can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Note that this gets the *whole* of the URL after the hostname, so `http://example.com/page/slug` will give `/page/slug`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do this a little hacky way if you know your application. I would use a regex to search for

```
[a-z].([(com|org|net)])
```