# Regex for Replacing Absolute URLs with Relative URLs

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I write a regex expression that will convert any absolute URLs to relative paths. For example:

```
src="http://www.test.localhost/sites/
```

would become

```
src="/sites/"
```

The domains are not static.

I can't use parse_url (as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017080/convert-absolute-to-relative-url-with-preg-replace)) because it is part of a larger string, that contains no-url data as well.

Comment: Replace `https?:\/\/[\w.-]+(?=\/)` with an empty string?

Comment: Your question is Unclear because you say that your data is "part of a larger string" but we don't know what that is.  If it is valid html, then you should only be reading Casimir's answer.  If it is not valid html, then you are likely to need cover a whole range of obscure cases -- so what is it?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can use the following regex:

```
/https?:\/{2}[^\/]+/
```

Which would match the following:

```
http://www.test.localhost/sites/
http://www.domain.localhost/sites/
http://domain.localhost/sites/
```

So it would be:

```
$domain = preg_replace('/https?:\/{2}[^\/]+/', '', $domain);
```

### Explanation

```
http: Look for 'http'
s?: Look for an 's' after the 'http' if there's one
: : Look for the ':' character
\/{2}: Look for the '//'
[^\/]+: Go for anything that is not a slash (/)
```

Comment: Will this work in a larger string, for example
<p> click <a href="http://www.test.localhost/sites/">here</a></p> would return:
<p> click <a href="/sites/">here</a></p>

Comment: @Sam If that's an HTML string, I wouldn't recommend using regex anyway. Use an [HTML parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+html+parser) to extract the URLs and then use the approach in the answer you referred to for parsing the URL parts.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this expression or an improved version of that might work to some extent:

```
^\s*src=["']\s*https?:\/\/(?:[^\/]+)([^"']+?)\s*["']$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMPWfa/1) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

---

#### Test

```
$re = '/^\s*src=["\']\s*https?:\/\/(?:[^\/]+)([^"\']+?)\s*["\']$/m';
$str = 'src=" http://www.test.localhost/sites/  "
src=" https://www.test.localhost/sites/"
src=" http://test.localhost/sites/   "
  src="https://test.localhost/sites/   "
      src="https://localhost/sites/   "
src=\'https://localhost/   \'
src=\'http://www.test1.test2.test3.test4localhost/sites1/sites2/sites3/   \'';
$subst = 'src="$1"';

var_export(preg_replace($re, $subst, $str));
```

#### Output

```
src="/sites/"
src="/sites/"
src="/sites/"
src="/sites/"
src="/sites/"
src="/"
src="/sites1/sites2/sites3/"
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the OP's actual input has `src` at the start of the line?  ...trick question, you don't -- because the question is Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML)
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xp->query('//@src') as $attr) {
    $url = parse_url($attr->nodeValue);

    if ( !isset($url['scheme']) || stripos($url['scheme'], 'http']) !== 0 )
        continue;

    $src = $url['path']
         . ( isset($url['query']) ? '?' . $url['query'] : '' )
         . ( isset($url['fragment']) ? '#' . $url['fragment'] : '' );

    $attr->parentNode->setAttribute('src', $src);
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

I added an `if` condition to skip cases when it isn't possible to say if the beginning of the src attribute is a domain or the beginning of the path. Depending of what you are trying to do, you can remove this test.

If you are working with parts of an html document (ie: not a full document), you have to change `$result = $dom->saveHTML()` with something like:

```
$result = '';
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result . = $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
}
```